# Firebase rules to check specific field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to access a data after checking a specific field value.Here am checking the **approved** field.

My fire base rule is

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "problems": {   


        ".read": "(data.child('approved').val() === 'true') || (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher')",
        ".write": true,     
        ".validate": "!newData.hasChild('approved') || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'",

        "approved":{
          ".write":"root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'"
        }      



    }
  }
}
```

user with role 'teacher' can read all the data but user with role 'other than teacher' can read only when the approved field is 'true'

Am facing the error for normal user. Firebase denies to read.

Comment: Please update your question to show the minimal code that reproduces that message.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're asking about: the `.write` rule on `approved` is meaningless in these rules. The `".write": true` on the level above means that every can write the entire `problems` node. There's no way to revoke permission on a lower level once it's granted. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Comment: Yes you are right but my question is regarding read operation.

Comment: I know, hence leaving a comment. But without seeing the minimal code that reproduces that message, it's hard to say why you get an error.